# Uploading HTML and CSS templates with Flask and React in Shopify App

Tags: python, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm currently working on a Shopify app using **Flask** for the server and **React** for the frontend. My goal is to create a functionality that allows users to upload HTML and CSS templates, each featuring a distinct webpage design, into a designated Shopify store.

I've successfully created a page using the Shopify Pages API with minimal HTML code. However, I'm struggling with the process of uploading the entire webpage along with its design.

If anyone has experience or insights into handling this scenario with Flask and React in a Shopify app, your guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in best practices or code snippets that can help me achieve this.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

In my implementation, I have used the Shopify Pages API to create a page with minimal HTML code. However, when attempting to upload the entire webpage with its design, I am not sure how to upload the css/js files with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.